# How would you analyze a large (300mb+) xml file and get it into a database?

Tags: mysql, xml, database

I want to take a massive XML file, a creative-commons licensed dictionary, and put it into a database. The problem is there is no documentation for the file. There are hundreds of thousands of words in this xml file, most of them are something like,

```
<entry key="a)rxiereu/s" type="main" id="n5063">
  <form opt="n"><orth extent="full" lang="greek" opt="n">a)rxiereu/s</orth></form>
  <sense level="0" n="0" id="n5063.0" opt="n"><trans opt="n"><tr opt="n">an arch-priest, chief-priest</tr></trans>, <usg opt="n">Hdt.</usg> [...] </sense>
</entry>
```

Is there any way of comparing all the `<entry>` tags and their attributes? E.g., almost all the `<entry>` tags have `<type="main">`, is there any way I can discover if any other attribute of type has a value other than main? Or all the attributes used by `entry` tags and all the attributes of `sense` tags throughout the entire document?

Finally, all I'm really familiar with is web-based technologies, HTML, Javascript, PHP, etc., So naturally I would think the best way to get this in a MySQL database would be to write a php script, is this necessarily correct?

Answer (score 2):

A good way to explore what is in this file is to use XQuery. For example, the answer to the question "is there any way I can discover if any other attribute of type has a value other than main?" can probably be answered by the query

```
distinct-values(//@type)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a XML parser. For C++ there is Tiny XML. But since you are familiar with Web technologies, i say you go with PHP.

Take a look at [Simple XML on PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

and this page that describes how to get attributes of element [SimpleXMLElement::attributes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)

I wonder if you will parse XML once, store it in Database or parsing would be required repeatedly. In former case you may even try TinyXML

Comment: For parsing 300mb+ using SimpleXML you`ll need to give PHP about 500mb+ of RAM. That`s too much.

Comment: One possible solution is to split the file in manageable sizes first.

Comment: Its not so easy to do. You need to split files in such way so the structure of XML will be not corrupted

Comment: Of course XML should not break at any cost. And the user should be having a decent understanding of the file under question for that.